# Almost Mathieu operator

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

I'm having trouble showing that the almost Mathieu operator given by

$$(Hu)_n = u_{n+1} + u_{n-1} + 2\lambda \cos \ [2 \pi (w + n\alpha)]u_n$$

Where $\lambda, \in \mathbb{R}$$, \alpha, w \in \mathbb{R/Z}$, $\alpha \not \in \mathbb{Q}$ are parameters, and $\lambda \not= 0$

where $H$ is the almost mathieu operator on  the Hilbert space $\mathcal l^{2}(\mathbb{Z})=\left \{ a=\left \{ a_{n} \right \}_{n=1}^{\infty}:a_{n}  \in  \mathbb{Z}, 1\leqslant n\leqslant \infty , \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left | a_{n} \right |^{2}< \infty  \right \}$ is bounded.

I tried to do the inner product to show that $\langle Ax,y\rangle =\langle x,Ay\rangle$ since according to Hellinger-Toeplitz theorem then the operator is bounded. But I end up with an odd answer.

In order for $\langle Ax,y\rangle =\langle x,Ay\rangle $ to be correct then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}[x_{n}\cdot y_{n+1}+x_{n}\cdot y_{n-1}]$ has to be equal to $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}[x_{n+1}\cdot y_{n}+x_{n-1}y_{n}]$ which it's clearly not for whenever $x$ is different from $y$??

Since

$\langle Ax,y\rangle $=$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}[(x_{n+1}+x_{n-1}+2\lambda \cos\ [2 \pi (w + n\alpha)]x_n)\cdot y_{n}]$

and

$\langle x,Ay\rangle$=$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}[x_{n}\cdot( y_{n+1}+ y_{n-1}+2\lambda \cos \ [2 \pi (w + n\alpha)]y_n)]$

Am I miscalculating or misunderstanding the inner product in $\mathcal l^{2}(\mathbb{Z})$?

According to articles etc. the Almost Mathieu operator is bounded and hence self-adjoint, but they don't prove it.

I also tried to calculate $||Hu||$ since if $0 <||Hu||< \infty \implies H$ is bounded.

This leads me to some ugly sums which I'm not sure whether all of them converge. If these sums converge however since we're in an Hilbert space, then it's bounded... But if it's bounded it should also be self-adjoint which I tried to show with no luck! All articles claim the operator is bounded and self-adjoint so what am I doing wrong here? :(

I should add I also try to show that the linear operator is continuous at a point (if it is then it's bounded), but I haven't managed yet.

Comment: You write "operator is bounded and hence self-adjoint", but it's the other way round, if an operator is self-adjoint, then it is bounded. There are lots of bounded operators that aren't self-adjoint. Is that just a typo, or a misunderstanding?

Comment: Well according to the Hellinger-Toeplitz theorem then any bounded operator defined everywhere on the entire space is self-adjoint? That's what I mean :). I know some operators are unbounded but self-adjoint (Quantum mechanics) hence they're not defined everywhere on the Hilbert space. (this is according to the book Functional analysis by Reed and Simon chapter III.5 p. 84) I'm doing my master on the spectrum of the almost mathieu operator, but first I must show that it's actually self-adjoint bounded, which the articles I read just dont write or state as if it's common knowledge without proof.

Comment: Ex. where they state it's bounded and self-adjoint: http://goo.gl/qYif8k

Comment: No, the Hellinger-Toeplitz theorem says that every globally defined self-adjoint operator is continuous (bounded). And at the beginning, you seem to try to use that: to show the boundedness, you try to show the self-adjointness. I've no idea what the "almost Mathieu operator" is, and it's not clear (to me) from your question, but it looks like showing that it is bounded directly would not be (very) difficult. But that's just a guess based on looks, without knowing what everything denotes, I can't say for sure.

Comment: That's what I thought Daniel, however I cannot manage... What information do you need.. Would be awesome if you could help me :) And yeah I can see what you mean about the Theorem.. Misunderstood there, but stil trying to show it in the top without success :/

Comment: Do not try to blank out your question; such edits are always going to be reverted and will get you in trouble with moderators if you persist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, be aware that you've misunderstood the definition of the Hilbert space $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$; it's the Hilbert space of all square-summable complex sequences indexed by $\mathbb{Z}$, i.e.,
$$
 \ell^2(\mathbb{Z}) := \Bigg\{a : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{C} \; \Bigg\vert \; \sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty \lvert a_n \rvert^2 < +\infty \Bigg\}
$$
endowed with the inner product
$$
 \langle a, b \rangle = \sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty \overline{a_n} b_n,
$$
if you take inner products to be linear in the second argument, or
$$
 \langle a, b \rangle = \sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty a_n\overline{b_n}
$$
if you take inner products to be linear in the first; this is a matter of convention and taste.

Now, the [Hellinger–Toeplitz theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellinger%E2%80%93Toeplitz_theorem) says that an everywhere defined symmetric operator on a Hilbert space is actually bounded (and hence, in particular, self-adjoint). Linearity of your almost-Mathieu operator $H$ is trivial, so you really have two tasks:

1. Show that $Hu \in \ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$ for all $u \in \ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$, so that $H$ is defined everywhere—this is *not* the same as showing it's bounded.
2. Given that $H$ is everywhere defined, show that $H$ is symmetric, i.e., $\langle H a, b \rangle = \langle a, H b \rangle$ for all $a$, $b \in \ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$.

With regard to the first task, observe that for $u \in \ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$,
$$
 Hu = Au + Bu + Cu, \quad (Au)_n := u_{n+1}, \quad (Bu)_n := u_{n-1}, \quad (Cu)_n := 2\lambda \cos(2\pi\omega(n+\alpha))u_n
$$
(in fact, it turns out that $A$ defines a well-known unitary operator on $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$ called the *left shift*, whilst $B = A^\ast$ is the *right shift*); hence it suffices to show that $Au$, $Bu$, and $Cu \in \ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$, i.e., that
$$
 \sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty \lvert u_{n+1} \rvert^2 < +\infty, \quad \sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty \lvert u_{n-1} \rvert^2 < +\infty, \quad \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \lvert2\lambda \cos(2\pi\omega(n+\alpha))u_n\rvert^2 < +\infty.
$$
Given that $u \in \ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$, why is this a triviality? Remember, if you're summing from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, you're completely free to reindex such a sum by $m = n-1$ or $m=n+1$ and get one and the same sum.

With regard to the second task, redoing you computation to take into account the fact that our sequences are complex valued and that the summation is over $\mathbb{Z}$ and *not* $\mathbb{N}$, you'll have to show equalities similar to what you're worried about, e.g.,
$$
 \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \overline{a_{n+1}}b_n = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \overline{a_n} b_{n-1}, \quad \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \overline{a_{n-1}}b_n = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \overline{a_n}b_{n+1};
$$
the key is the observation above about summing from $-\infty$ to $\infty$.

Comment: Branimir I still don't understand how I show the last equalities are true?

Comment: If you set $m = n+1$, say, then $\overline{a_{n+1}}b_n = \overline{a_m}b_{m-1}$. But now, what's the relation between $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \overline{a_{n+1}}b_n = \sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty \overline{a_m}b_{m-1}$ and $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \overline{a_n}b_{n-1}$?

Comment: Brilliant :) Thanks ! You're awesome ;) I did too many brain farts :S